# How to send Grafana reset email from Grafana docker image

Tags: dockerfile, grafana, docker-image, grafana-alerts

I have created a Dockerfile and created a image with grafana. I have up the docker container.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM grafana/grafana

ENV GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM "false"
ENV GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED "false"
ENV GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE "Viewer"
ENV GF_SMTP_ENABLED "true"
ENV GF_SMTP_HOST "smtp.gmail.com:587"
ENV GF_SMTP_USER "test@gmail.com"
ENV GF_SMTP_PASSWORD ""
ENV GF_SMTP_SKIP_VERIFY "true"
ENV GF_SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS "admin@grafana.localhost"
ENV GF_SMTP_FROM_NAME "Grafana"
ENV GF_SMTP_EHLO_IDENTITY "dashboard.example.com"
```

I was able to up the container using this command.

```
docker run -d -p 6375:3000 --name grafan grafana-n
```

I created a notification channel

[image]

From here i can send test mail.

But I can't sent grafana forgot password reset email. when i clicked on send reset email button it displays the notification email sent but I can't see it in my gmail.

But if i locally up it with configs in

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

I can send reset password email. what can be the issue?

Comment: 1.) Increase Grafana logs level and check logs 2.) Enable Gmail `Less secure app access`

Comment: @JanGaraj I have enabled  Gmail Less secure app access. In the grafana ui screen it shows the notification Email sent. But I can't see in my inbox.

Comment: @JanGaraj Is my way is correct?